# Python keeps giving 'partially initialized module has no attribute' error, despite having tavern function defined in file

Tags: python, error-handling, python-module

I am trying to make an RPG game using python, and keep running into this error.

> "partially initialized module (rpgLocations) has no attribute 'Tavern'"

Whenever I first run my program for testing, the file runs just fine, but then after a few times running it, it gives me this error. If I delete the file and create it again with a different name, it does the same thing. It works a few times then it doesn't.

No modules I imported have this attribute.

Tavern Function:

```
import main
def Tavern():
    main.clear()
    main.PlayerStatus.CurrentPlayerLocation = 'Tavern'
    print('What would you like to do?\n\n\n')
    while True:
        main.pInput = input('1. Trade\n2. View quests\n3. gamble\n4. Look around\n5. Idk,\n6. Leave\n\n>')
        if main.pInput == '1':
            print('test works')
            break
        elif main.pInput == '6':
            NavigationPanel()
```

in main.py, I import the file,

```
import rpgLocations
```

and call it later on

```
rpgLocations.Tavern()
```

Answer (score 1):

To help diagnose this:

Is there any other files call rpgLocations within the same directory?

Also you seem to have a circular reference on your imports (main imports rpgLocations which imports main, and so on).

Comment: There are no other files that call rpgLocations. I use main.py for the use of all of my functions. Yes, there are circular imports. Does that prevent python from running properly? If so, how could I fix it? I don't want to put all of my locations.py in main.py as it is somewhat repetitive and would clutter all of my code. Thanks in advance.